# save best model in pytorch with optuna

Tags: model, pytorch, optuna

is there an easy way to save the best model from an optuna study in pytorch?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `LightGBMTuner`, you can use `LightGBMTuner.get_best_booster` method to get the best model. Otherwise, you need to persist trained models by yourself (c.f., [How to save machine learning models trained in objective functions?](https://optuna.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-save-machine-learning-models-trained-in-objective-functions)).

reference: https://github.com/optuna/optuna/issues/2085